# What will happen when we launch? (aka: OMG! What happened to my privileges?!)

Tags: support, reputation

At long last, the site will launch! All our hard work here is finally paying off. This is quite exciting. But please be aware that this is not without cost. As painful as it may be initially, users may lose some privileges for a little while.

On beta sites, some privileges require less rep than they do on graduated sites. So, for instance, where you can now create a new tag with 150 rep, you'll need 300 after we graduate. What rep is required to do what can be found [on our FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) and on [the list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/), but as a help it's posted below.

Don't be surprised by this, and be aware that we local moderators can't do anything about it. The only way to restore lost privileges is to keep asking great questions and writing great answers (and voting. Always vote. You have 30 votes a day. Use them, please).

How do we get people here to have higher reputation scores? Keep voting up those good questions and answers, that's how. Edit questions and answers into shape when they need it, so that others will vote them up. **And please, don't forget to vote on questions.**

(PS: you get up to an extra ten question votes per day if you vote on enough questions too)

---

[**Table of reps and privileges**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared):

```
                                                  Where we're gonna be 
                                           Where we are now ↴        ↓
Action                                     Private ß Public ß Launched     SO
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Ask and answer questions                           1        1        1      1
Ask and answer questions on meta                   5        5        5    N/A
Skip lecture on how to ask                       N/A      N/A      N/A     10
Add images, 2+ link, answer protected questions    1       10       10     10
Create community wiki answers                     10       10       10     10
Vote up                                            1       15       15     15
Flag posts                                        15       15       15     15
Talk in chat                                      20       20       20     20
Comment everywhere                                 1       50       50     50
Set bounties                                      75       75       75     75
Create chat rooms                                100      100      100    100
Edit community wiki w/o approval                   1      100      100    100
Vote down (-1 rep on answers)                      1      125      125    125
Vote in moderator elections                      N/A      N/A      150    150
One time +100 rep to all linked accounts         200      200      200    200
Reduced advertisements                           200      200      200    200
View close votes                                   1      250      250    250
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate own questions    1      250      250    250
Nominate for moderator                           N/A      N/A      300    300
Create new tags                                    1      150      300   1500
Retag questions                                    1      200      500    500
Show total up and down vote counts               100      750     1000   1000
Create a gallery chat room                      1000     1000     1000   1000
Edit other's posts w/o approval                  500     1000     2000   2000
Approve or reject other's edits                  500     1000     2000   2000
Suggest tag synonyms                            1250     1250     2500   2500
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate questions        1      500     3000   3000
Approve tag wiki edits                           750     1500     5000   5000
Access moderation tools                         1000     2000      10K    10K
Reduce captchas                                 1000     2000      10K    10K
Review chat flags                                10K      10K      10K    10K
Protect questions                               1750     3500      15K    15K
Trusted user                                    2000     4000      20K    20K
Painting of unicorns, signed by Jeff and Joel                     200K   200K
```

---

For the folks that don't understand why this is so important:

As sites are launched (private beta) they need a period to get a lot of content in a few days to help everybody figure out the intent of the site. That's when we added all sorts of questions, including those on NoSQL and relational databases. There were questions about cloud databases and the like.

Then we hit public beta, where we demonstrated that people would actually visit a site like this for more day-to-day usage. Then it was important to give people the ability to moderate the site on their own and build their rep on the site.

Now we've proven that this site is a resource that people are gonna want to use regularly, we need to transition to a more mature scale of how the abilities are regulated. And that's what this transition point is about.

Should we get to a few hundred thousand users we'll scale up again to the "SO" scale. We have plenty of time to worry about that, tho ;)

If you have more questions, post them below and I'll answer them in turn.

Comment: Not only is this **Not a Real Question**, but the OP is encouraging us to post "more questions" *as answers* - and he will answer them (presumably in the comments!). I'm voting to close this as off-topic for mdba.se or migrate to a blog post. As it stands it is a gross misuse of the SE system :P

Comment: Cute Jack. I think we all know mods get to abuse the system (go see the other metas on the network :p) hehe. I actually need to edit this a bit more later today. Actually, I think dori did do the editing :p

Comment: From the list above, does Jon Skeet have a painting of a Unicorn in his office ???

Comment: Do we have an official date of launch ? Will the privileges shift the day of the launch or prior ?

Comment: He does. (it may not be in his office, idk) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/ for more info. The official date is supposed to be today, but that may not be solid. The privileges shift when they update the site in their database (it's a pretty smooth procedure nowadays)

Comment: The site header has nice structure chart appearance. Sweet !!!